# How to make automatic filter based on query in opensearch/elastisearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, opensearch

I am using opensearch for marketplace search. I use field "product_name" for search. I also have a field "brand" and I want that when people search for a product from a certain brand, if it is in “brand”, a filter will automatically turn on so that we search only among products with this brand. For example if someone search "toyota car" i want to have filter toyota on "brand" field to automatically turn on. And if someone search "new nissan car" i want to have filter nissan on "brand" field to automatically turn on. How to do that?